# PHRETS, Search not working on live server

Tags: php, phrets

Running search queries on my local machine using PHRETS and connected to a rets server, I am able to get any information I need.

After deploying vendor folder and code to live server, I can login but not search parameters are accepted. I've tried small and simple for just a lakefront property and nothing is accepted.

I launched from GoDaddy. Is there a port I need to listen for or is there something I have to have the rets server do?

Again, long story short, it accepts my login and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have at least php 5.6 in your website.. you may get the dead nothing happening just like you describe or in some cases you may get this nasty error across the screen... in either case upgrading your php version above 5.4 will take care of it.. here is one error it may give also..
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/retspro/public_html/beard/vendor/illuminate/support/Traits/Macroable.php on line 56
what a horrible looking thing....